# The .delete() method in java is not working

Tags: java, delete-file

Files inside the (Tracks)directory was not deleted. The method deletes the wav files stored in the directory.

```
public boolean deleteTrack(response)  {
    ListIterator<Track> trackListIterator = this.trackList.listIterator();

    //tracklist is the linked list on which I'm using list iterator. I'm storing song which is a object inside it. this object has a fn() that returns content root path not absolute path.

    String path = "";
    while (trackListIterator.hasNext()) {
     //RESPONSE == PARAMETER
        if (trackListIterator.next().getTrackName().equals(response)) {
            trackListIterator.previous();
            path = trackListIterator.next().getTrackPath();//this is the fn() that 
             returns content root path example(src/Exploit/org/Trackstore/Music/Action Movie Music-FesliyanStudios.wav).
            break;
        }
    }
   
    File file = new File(path);
 //here I'm taking absolute path for deleting actual wav file from the computer.
    File toBeDeleted = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return toBeDeleted.delete();// returns false everytime.
}
```

[image: file structure]

Comment: Have you checked that toBeDeleted points to a file which exists?

Comment: "Note that the Files class defines the delete method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted." From the Javadocs of `File`, either you are passing it a bad `path`, or an `IOException` is getting thrown for some reason.

Comment: @tgdavies . Yes, I have checked many time and that was not an issue at all.

Comment: Take @nexevis advice and use Files.delete.

Answer (score 2):

The old API has many issues. For example, most methods return a boolean to indicate the result which is stupid and unjavalike - fortunately, there is a new API that fixes these issues.

Use it and you'll know *WHY* it failed. If that's too much effort, well, there isn't much to say. It didn't delete. No idea why, and there's no way to ask that API about why.

The new API lives in the `java.nio.file` package.

Replace this:

```
File f = new File("path/to/file");
if (!f.delete()) { ... it didn't work ... }
```

with:

```
Path p = Paths.get("path/to/file");
try {
    Files.delete(p);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // the exception will explain everything there is to be said about why it did not work!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. "  . This is what the java.nio.file package returns. What should I do for correction?

Comment: @Kaal-EL Do you have the file open in a text editor or something?

Comment: @Nexevis Nope, It is actually a music file of (.wav) format. and I'm not playing the song either so. I have just created the song object in which there are fields having name,  duration , content path and fn() like play music and stored it in an linkedlist

Comment: @Kaal-El Might worth rebooting your computer to see if a process still has it open, and if it works afterwards, that was the issue.  If it still does not work that means there is something wrong with your code that is keeping the file open when it shouldn't be.

Comment: There must be a concurrency issue inside my program and I'm not able to figure it out

Comment: 'another process' rather strongly suggests it is not _YOUR_ program that's doing it. Also, this is a common windows bugbear (other OSes just let you delete the file which won't actually go away until all relevant processes are done with it). On unix you can use `lsof`, on windows you can use Process Explorer (you have to install that, it's from sysinternals). There are [many solutions](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/windows/how-know-which-process-using-file-or-folder-windows/) to figure out which process has that file open.

Comment: The (Java.exe) is the only process, accessing that wav file. Which seems obvious   as I'm using jvm. It's just ridiculous.  @rzwitserloot

Comment: Intriguing - then the error message is a bit off. Time to go on a hunt in your code for accidental resource abuse (where you open a resource but don't close it). Tools like sonarqube and the like will automatically tell you all the places where you do this.